# How to return object array into arrays?

Tags: javascript, object, multidimensional-array, array.prototype.map

I have been experimenting with the map/filter/reduce functions and I want to stray away from using for loops.

I want to turn the object arrays

```
var foo = [{"z":5, "y":10, "x":15}, {"z":30, "y":40, "x":50}];
```

into multidimensional a array. Basically the final output should be [[5, 10, 15], [30, 40, 50]] with no objects, just arrays. 
I know how to do it for a single object:

```
Object.keys(foo[0]).map(function(key) { 
  return foo[0][key]; 
});
```

which gives me the first array [5, 10, 15]. But I want it to iterate for the rest so I know I need a .map function. So far I have:

```
foo.map(function(bar) {
        var foobar = Object.keys(bar).map(function(key){ 
            return foo[key]; 
        }); 
    return foo; 
});
```

Can someone explain what I'm doing incorrectly

Comment: probably need to consider sort order also since object keys can have different orders depending on how object was constructed

Answer (score 2):

There's a very simple way to do this:

```
var newFoo = foo.map(el=>Object.values(el));
```

This is modern, ES2017 code. [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) gets the values of an object in an array. The code says "for every element in `foo`, get the values of the object and return them in an array".

You could do this in pre-2017 code with something like this:

```
var newFoo = foo.map(function(el) {
    var values = [];
    for (var key in el) {
        if (el.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            values.push(el[key]);
        }
    }
    return values;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `return test;` instead `return the Object.keys` logic

```js
var foo = [{"z":5, "y":10, "x":15}, {"z":30, "y":40, "x":50}];

var fooArray = foo.map(function(bar) {
    return Object.keys(bar).map(function(key){ 
        return bar[key]; 
    }); 
});

console.log(fooArray)
```

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
// for each object in the array
foo.map(function(bar) {
    // return an array
    // containing the values of each key in the object
    return Object.keys(bar).map(function(key){ 
        return bar[key]; 
    }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, just with two mistakes:

1. Should return "bar[key]" instead of "foo[key]" in the inner map function.
2. Should return "foobar" instead of "foo" in the outer map function.

```js
foo.map(function(bar) {
        var foobar = Object.keys(bar).map(function(key){ 
            return bar[key]; 
        }); 
    return foobar; 
});
```